# Accessing the new Alternative access mapping URL will ask for the username 3 times, then will show a blank white page

Tags: administration, central-administration, url, sharepoint-on-prem, alternate-access-mapping

We have a sharepoint farm on-premises 2013 and we have defined 2 alternative access mapping urls for our web application, as follow:-

```
http://www.OurIntranet.intra Zone =  Internet 

https://www.OurIntranet.intra  Zone = Custom
```

and users were able to access these 2 urls without any problem. but our customer have asked us to change the above 2 url from `www.OurIntranet.intra` to be `www.MainIntranet.intranet`. so our system admins made the changes to the DNS. then i went to the `Central Administration` >> `Configure alternate access mappings`, and i chnage the above 2 zones to match the new url. Aafter that i tried to access the new URL `http://www.OurIntranet.intra` and `https://www.ourintranet.intra`, but i was prompted to enter the username and password for 3 times, then a blank white page was displayed.. so not sure what is going on ? now since i was prompted to enter the username/password so the request have reached sharepoint in a way or another. but not sure why it keeps asking me for the username/password for 3 times then i got a white page... without showing any error. so can anyone advice how we can fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Are you getting login prompted on the server?

Comment: @Mike can you advice more on this please? what do u exactly mean? now i tried accessing the sites from the sharepoint server itself and yea i got the prompted ..but this is the case even when i was accessing the old url, but of course after typing the username i will login to the sites..

Comment: Are you getting the login prompt when you are logged onto the server? If so, that's the loopback check that you'll need to disable or add to the `backconnectionhostnames`. See here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896861/you-receive-error-401-1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrate Also, check the IIS bindings and flush your DNS cache.

Comment: @Mike maybe this is a different issue.. as even on the old url which were working well `http://www.OurIntranet.intra` ,, i will be prompted for username/password first, then i can access the sites correctly.. but on the new url i will be prompted to enter the username for 3 times then i will get a blank white page.. so being prompted for username/password is not the real problem ...

Comment: That also may happen if you are using Kerberos and you don't have the correct SPN entered for the hostname, or a duplicate SPN issue. Also check the IIS bindings to make sure they are correct.

Comment: @Mike now i do not think it is related to kerberos ,, as we did not do any major change to the web application. we only change the DNS server to match the new urls and then we update the alternative access mapping urls.. now the old urls are working well.. but the new ones will be prompting for username/password then redirect to blank white page..

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue before in SharePoint 2013. If you check the ULS logs you are likely to find some entries complaining about claims. In SharePoint 2013 in order to access a site the site needs to be listed in alternate access mapping. It sounds from your description like you changed the old URLs to the new ones. I would suggest adding the old ones back in, in addition to the new ones. In my experience this should solve your problem.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2013/05/27/alternate-access-mappings-aams-explained/

Comment: now when i do so , and i try to access the new URL i will be redirected to the old url so if i type the new url `https://www.mainintranet.intra` i will be redirected to `https://www.OurIntranet.intra`... now i check the alternative access mapping again, and i can see that since i have 2 custom zones and 2 Internet zones.. so the new url `https://www.mainintranet.intra` is having the `https://www.OurIntranet.intra` as its `Public URL for Zone` inside the `Central Administration >> Configure alternate access mappings`

Comment: You just have to set the internal and the extranet urls